# Pycharm: set terminal size

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I'm trying to set the terminal size of the `pycharm` terminal so `pandas` will wrap like I want to. I know that I can do

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
```

for each thing I run.  But pandas detects the terminal size and when I run

```
pd.core.series.get_terminal_size()
Out[94]: os.terminal_size(columns=80, lines=24)
```

Is there a way to make the terminal size larger so `pandas` will auto-detect this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not exacly what you were looking for, but it might be a valid second option if you don't find a good alternative.

---

What I did was to add the lines of code you showed to the startup script for the `Python` terminal (or console) in `PyCharm`.

The setting is located at

```
Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Console >> Python Console
```

See also my screenshot:

[image]

And there you can include some code lines that should be executed everytime you start the console.

Comment: I tried that, but it is only for the console.  Not the regular execution.